# How to enable Data Translation for Custom Field Values Of Custom Object?

Tags: translation-workbench

I have a custom object and I want to translate Data for value inside custom field when I'll use `Field.Value` on my LWC Component.

Any idea on how to enable Data Translation for Custom Field Values?

I am not able to find this in my Salesforce Org , please advise if I am missing any permission or any other option is available.

[Data Translation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.comm_enable_data_translation.htm&type=5)

Comment: Does this help (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_translation_enable_custom_fields.htm&type=5)

Comment: I had the same issue and I can see the option in Company Information section to enable Data translation. After enable it, I can see only Product and Record Alert object in the export. I believe Salesforce doesn't support data translation for the other objects at this moment.